# Bootloader - Doesn't jmp or load second sector correctly

Tags: assembly, x86, bootloader

I've been desperatly trying to make a bootloader. At a point I got it working but now it doesn't work anymore. When I run it, it prints an A and a B. So that means it does actualy do the read, but for some reason when it jumps it doesn't execute the code I put at the second sector of my USB drive.

I wonder if there's something wrong with my adressing or jumps?

I included the image of my USB memory

```
[bits 16]
[org 0x7C00]

jmp Start

;%include "BIOS_Parameter_Block.inc"
;%include "Extensions.inc"
;%include "Print.inc"

; Prepare Stack Segment
;-----------------------------------------------------------------
Start:
xor ax, ax
mov ds, ax
mov es, ax
mov fs, ax
mov gs, ax
mov ss, ax

mov sp, 0x7C00              ; Move Stack into SP
mov bp, sp                  ; Store current Stack Base

; Print Character to Make Sure Bootloader Has Reached this Point
;-----------------------------------------------------------------
mov ah, 0x0E                ; Print Character to Screen
mov bh, 0x00                ; No Page Numbering
mov bl, 0x07                ; White Text, Black Background
mov al, 65                  ; Print Letter A
int 0x10

; Check if INT0x13 Extentions are Supported
;-----------------------------------------------------------------
mov ah, 0x41                ; Set Function 0x41
mov word bx, 0x55AA          
push dx                     ; Save old Drive Identifier
mov dl, 0x80                ; Load 'Active' ID Into dl
int 0x13                    ; Call Interupt
jc short unsupported        ; If Extentions aren't Supported, Jump
clc                         ; Clear Carry Bit

; Read from the device.
;-----------------------------------------------------------------
mov si, DAPS                ; Load DAPS Struct to DS:SI
mov ah, 0x42                ; Read Functions (AL Ignored)
mov dl, 0x80                ; Load 'Active' ID Into dl
int 0x13
jc short unsupported        ; If something goes wrong...

mov ah, 0x0E                ; Print Character to Screen
mov bh, 0x00                ; No Page Numbering
mov bl, 0x07                ; White Text, Black Background
mov al, 66                  ; Print Letter B
int 0x10

; IT DOES PRINT THIS ABOVE

jmp 0x0:0x7E00                  ; Jump to main

; Errors 
;-----------------------------------------------------------------
unsupported:
mov ah, 0x0E                ; Print Letter F, Gives Indication of Failure
mov bh, 0x00
mov bl, 0x07
mov al, 70
int 0x10

clc
hlt
; Memory Data Structures and Other Variables
;-----------------------------------------------------------------
; Disk Address Packet Structure (Used For Loading Rest of OS)
DAPS: db 0x10               ; Size of Structure (16 bytes)
      db 0                  ; Always 0
      dw 1                  ; Number of Sectors to Read (1x512)
      dw 0x7E00             ; Offset to load to.
      dw 0x0000             ; Segment to load to.
      dq 1                  ; Read from Second Block

; Fill Out Rest of Bootloader
;-----------------------------------------------------------------
times 510-($-$$) db 0

db 0x55, 0xAA               ; Add Boot Record Signature
```

Stage2 placed at the second sector

```
 [ORG 0x7E00]
 [bits 16]

 mov ah, 0x0E                ; Print Character to Screen
 mov bh, 0x00                ; No Page Numbering
 mov bl, 0x07                ; White Text, Black Background
 mov al, 67                  ; Print Letter C
 int 0x10
 cli
 hlt
```

Hope you guys could help me!

[image: Memory of Bootloader]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

int 0x13 bios calls generally use the drive ID in the DL register - 0x80 is usually the ID of the first HDD. You may need to change this in order to load the additional sector from a USB drive (which presumably is not the first HDD).

Comment: I understand what you mean but how can I figure out what the Drive ID for my USB is?

Comment: That's a good question - and I can't immediately remember how I've dealt with this in the past. My suspicion is that it will show up in the HD range (>0x80), but I can't confirm this. Apparently there is _some_ correspondence between windows drive letters and bios drive ID (http://support.microsoft.com/kb/62571), and you may be able to get some information about the installed drives using int 0x13 AH=0x48 (http://www.delorie.com/djgpp/doc/rbinter/id/21/7.html)

Comment: Here we go - it appears when the BIOS transfers control to the loaded code it will pre-set the DL register as the drive ID for the device that sector was loaded from (http://wiki.osdev.org/MBR_(x86)). I can't vouch for how 'standard' this is - but I'm pretty sure this is behaviour I've used in the past without problems..

Comment: Yeah! I figured that out too. In the end it actually ended up being something really different. The BIOS could only reconize the USB as harddrive when the signature of the EBBP was 0 instead of 0x29 or 0x28. Really weird.. But thanks for the help! Vote up for you!:P